# How can I make Motif Push Button widget to appear as permanently pushed?

Tags: c, unix, x11, freebsd, motif

I have written a simple tool to select an audio channel in FreeBSD.

This is the code:

xaudio.c

```
#include <Xm/Xm.h>
#include <Xm/PushB.h>
#include <Xm/MainW.h>
#include <Xm/RowColumn.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "devices.h"

struct button_data {
   int device_num;
   Widget button;
};

/* GLOBAL VARIABLES */
int num_devices;
struct device *devices;
struct button_data *buttons;

void button_callback(Widget widget, XtPointer client_data, XtPointer call_data);
void create_device_buttons(Widget parent, struct device *devices, int num_devices);

void button_callback(Widget widget, XtPointer client_data, XtPointer call_data) {
   int i;
   struct button_data *data = (struct button_data *)client_data;
   int device_num = data->device_num;

   // unclick all other buttons
   for (i = 0; i < num_devices; i++) {
      if (buttons[i].button != widget) {
         XtVaSetValues(buttons[i].button, XmNset, False, NULL);
      }
   }

   // click this button
   XtVaSetValues(widget, XmNset, True, NULL);
   
   // set audio device
   set_audio_device(device_num);
}

void create_device_buttons(Widget parent, struct device *devices, int num_devices) {
   int i;
   XmString label;
   struct button_data *data;
   Arg args[5];
   int n;

   buttons = malloc(num_devices * sizeof(struct button_data));
   if (buttons == NULL) {
      perror("Failed to allocate memory");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   for (i = 0; i < num_devices; i++) {
      // create button
      n = 0;
      label = XmStringCreateLocalized(devices[i].description);
      XtSetArg(args[n], XmNlabelString, label); n++;
      buttons[i].button = XmCreatePushButton(parent, "device_button", args, n);
      XmStringFree(label);
      XtManageChild(buttons[i].button);

      // set button data
      buttons[i].device_num = devices[i].number;

      // set button callback
      XtAddCallback(buttons[i].button, XmNactivateCallback, button_callback, &buttons[i]);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   XtAppContext app;
   Widget top_level, main_window, button_rowcolumn;
   int default_device;

   int n=0;
   Arg args[10];

   top_level = XtVaOpenApplication(&app, "XAudio", NULL, 0, &argc, argv, NULL, sessionShellWidgetClass, NULL);
   main_window = XmCreateMainWindow(top_level, "main_window", NULL, 0);
   XtManageChild(main_window);
   n=0;
   XtSetArg(args[n], XmNorientation, XmVERTICAL); n++;
   button_rowcolumn = XmCreateRowColumn(main_window, "button_rowcolumn", args, n);    
   XtManageChild(button_rowcolumn);

   /* GET LIST OF DEVICES AND DEFAULT DEVICE */
   default_device = get_default_device(&devices, &num_devices);

   int i=0;
   for(i=0; i<num_devices; i++) {
        printf("%d %s\n", devices[i].number, devices[i].description);
  }

   create_device_buttons(button_rowcolumn, devices, num_devices);
   
   XtRealizeWidget(top_level);
   
   /* CLICK DEFAULT BUTTON */
   if (default_device >= 0) {
      XtVaSetValues(buttons[default_device].button, XmNset, True, NULL);
   }

   XtAppMainLoop(app);
   
   free(devices);
   free(buttons);
   
   return 0;
}
```

devices.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct device {
   int number;
   char description[256];
};

void set_audio_device(int device_num) {
   char command[256];
   sprintf(command, "sysctl hw.snd.default_unit=%d", device_num);
   system(command);
}

int get_default_device(struct device **devices, int *num_devices) {
   FILE *fp;
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;
   ssize_t read;
   int num_dev = 0;
   int default_device = -1;

   fp = popen("cat /dev/sndstat", "r");
   if (fp == NULL) {
      perror("Failed to run command");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
      if (strstr(line, "pcm") == line) {
         // line starts with "pcm", so it is a device line
         // increase number of devices and reallocate memory
         num_dev++;
         *devices = realloc(*devices, num_dev * sizeof(struct device));
         if (*devices == NULL) {
            perror("Failed to allocate memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }

         // get device number
         sscanf(line, "pcm%d:", &(*devices)[num_dev - 1].number);

         // get description
         char *start = strchr(line, '<');
         char *end = strchr(line, '>');
         if (start != NULL && end != NULL) {
            int length = end - start - 1;
            strncpy((*devices)[num_dev - 1].description, start + 1, length);
            (*devices)[num_dev - 1].description[length] = '\0';
         }

         // check if this is the default device
         if (strstr(line, "default") != NULL) {
            default_device = num_dev - 1;
         }
      }
   }

   *num_devices = num_dev;
   pclose(fp);
   return default_device;
}
```

devices.h:

```
#ifndef DEVICES_H
#define DEVICES_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct device {
   int number;
   char description[256];
};

void set_audio_device(int device_num);
int get_default_device(struct device **devices, int *num_devices);

#endif
```

And the corresponding makefile (for FreeBSD):

```
CC = cc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/local/include
LDFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -L/usr/local/lib -lXm -lXt -lX11 

all: xaudio

xaudio: xaudio.o devices.o
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ xaudio.o devices.o

xaudio.o: xaudio.c devices.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

devices.o: devices.c devices.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
        rm -f *.o xaudio
```

The program compiles and works (it switches the audio channel as expected). However, my intended behaviour was that the channel selected appeared as a permanently pushed button, and that when a new channel was selected the pushed button changed accordingly. Sort kind of "selectable button set".

It is my understanding that such behaviour was achieved by the following widget parameter:

```
XtVaSetValues(buttons[default_device].button, XmNset, True, NULL);
```

However, as seen here, this is not happening and the buttons appear always unclicked except the normal dynamic click effect when pressed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The desired behaviour you describe is what "radio buttons" are for. In Motif, I believe you need the XmCreateRadioBox function.

Comment: I understand that the RadioButton is the canonical and "proper" way of implementing this behaviour, but I wanted to know if this can be achieved with a PushButton. Maybe the right question would had been: can a push button be configured programmatically so it is "always pushed"?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

No, XmPushButton cant be configured to looked always pushed.
Try using XmToggleButton instead of XmPushButton. Set XmNindicatorOn to False to get rid of the diamond checkbox. Then XmNset,False will make it looked pressed.

Comment: Clearly it is best to use the widgets as they were intended to be used. Just for the shake of understanding a bit better Motif, what about changing resources when the button is click and reverting them back when a different button is click?

Comment: If you look at a man page of XmToggleButton the access column will indicate if the resource can be set at creation(C), gotten(G), or set(S). You can change resources at runtime using XtVaSetValues(). Just make sure the callback has access to the button Widget.